# Recreate jQuery link effect in CSS3

Tags: css, css-transitions

Does anyone know how to recreate this link effect that is done in jQuery in pure CSS3?
The effect can be seen at: http://www.yuhong-ng.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same html :

```
<a href="#" id="liveshows" style="margin-top: -40px;">
  <span class="top">Live Shows</span>
  <span class="bottom">Live Shows</span>
</a>
```

Same base CSS :

```
#navigation li a {
    height:80px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow';
    font-weight: bold;
}
#navigation li,#navigation li a {
    float: left;    
}
#navigation li a span {
    display:block;
    height:32px;
    padding:8px 20px 0 20px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

An some new CSS3 stuff :

```
#navigation li a {
  -webkit-transition: margin-top 500ms linear;
     -moz-transition: margin-top 500ms linear;
          transition: margin-top 500ms linear;
}

#navigation li a:hover {
  margin-top: -40px;
}
```

So, what happens here ?
On hover, your JavaScript animates the `margin` property to -40px. Simple stuff.
So, in CSS, you need a transition property and, on :hover, change the `margin`. Same stuff.

A better version would use 3dtransforms, because it avoids repainting. It depends really if this effect is alone on your page (then transition on `margin` is fine) or if the website is "effect rich" (then repaints are to be tracked and eliminated.)

```
#navigation li a {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 500ms linear;
     -moz-transition: -moz-transform 500ms linear;
          transition: -ms-transform 500ms linear;
          transition: transform 500ms linear;
}

#navigation li a:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-40px,0px);
     -moz-transform: translate3d(0,-40px,0px);
      -ms-transform: translate3d(0,-40px,0px);
          transform: translate3d(0,-40px,0px);
}
```

More about repaints (must see video) : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x0VR3lUOpdc

Comment: Thanks for the video. Was unaware of repainting!